# How To Detect If On A Single Post / Page on Tumblr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I haven't found a way to detect if user is currently viewing a page, post or an entire list of articles. WordPress has functions like is_page, is_single, etc for that, but does anyone have a way for Tumblr? I'm currently hacking it with the following code:

```
$(function() {
    var uri_root = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/';
    var uri = window.location.href;
    if(uri_root !== uri){
        alert("Viewing a single POST or PAGE!");
    }
});
```

I'm wondering if that is the best way of doing this or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each post has a div of class post. So, count the number of div's with post classes.

Something like this: `$('div.post').length` or `document.getElementsByClassName('post')` if there is no jQuery.

Answer (score 30):

I've found a more adequate solution. According to Tumblr's documentation:

> {block:IndexPage} {/block:IndexPage}  Rendered on index (post) pages.
>
> {block:PermalinkPage} {/block:PermalinkPage}  Rendered on post permalink pages.

So basically, code wrapped in the **IndexPage** block will run only on pages that can display more then one post whether it's a text, photo, video, etc post.

...and code wrapped in the **PermalinkPage** will only run for single post permalink pages.

Comment: i try this solution works fine, thanks dude +1 for your answer!

Comment: This solution is indeed A LOT more adequate than the JS solution.

Comment: What about detecting Ask page? Are there blocks for this?

I've embedded an ask box iframe on my page, but I only want to show it when the user navigates to the ask page. Currently it shows up on both ask and permalink page.

Comment: @Owzzz there isn't one for those static pages, however `{block:Date}{/block:Date}` only shows stuff for single post pages, meaning you can semi sort between the two. As for embedding an ask box into an ask page, this is unnecessary as tumblr already generates an ask page with an ask box for you.

Answer (score 0):

To detect if it's on a **page** or **post**, I've created this script that worked well for me.

```
{block:PermalinkPage} 
  var page = {JSPostID};
  if(page == '') alert('Page!');
  else alert('Post');
{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

---

Or use the simplest functions

```
function isPage(){
    {block:PermalinkPage} if({JSPostID} == '') return true; {/block:PermalinkPage}
    return false;
}
function isPost(){
    {block:PermalinkPage} if({JSPostID} != '') return true; {/block:PermalinkPage}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please detail the `{JSPostID}` variable?